# pip throws exception during installation of package

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

Rookie mistake here.
I did install Homebrew and pip on my mac, but there were some complications during installation.
For example, for pip I got Permissions denied. I went Google and found "sudo - H" solution. But there was some message regarding disabling of wheel and log, and I accidentally quit terminal.

Is there any command for pip and Homebrew to get a status report, like everything is okay or delete and reinstall is the best way?

Edit:
Tried to install a package in pip and Homebrew, as suggested, w/o sudo -h got this:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
 status = self.run(options, args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
 prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
 **kwargs
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
 self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
 isolated=self.isolated,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
 clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
 shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
 with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bellite.pyc'
```

But it seems related to Python 2.7, which I am not interested at all.

When I used sudo -h, I got:

```
The directory '/Users/SimonOsipov/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/SimonOsipov/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

Homebrew installed package with 0 problems

Comment: You could try installing a package via homebrew/pip to see that it's working...

Comment: You could try brew reinstall command.

Comment: Try to install any package. If `pip` throws an error regarding file permissions it's not working properly.

Comment: Tried, check edit.

Comment: You should make your question title more informative than "How to check if everything is okay".

Comment: Changed title to be more informative.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with `pip` throwing a permissions error; you just have to use `pip install --user` to install under your user instead of system-wide (which requires `sudo`). Also, how is this question related to Homebrew?

Comment: @bfontaine I would like to thank you for your suggestion with --user. Tried this approach and everything went without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `Permission denied` error because by default `pip` tries to install its packages system-wide. There’s nothing not working properly here.

You can install packages under your own user with `--user`:

```
pip install --user ...
```

> Is there any command for pip and Homebrew to get a status report, like everything is okay or delete and reinstall is the best way?

Homebrew has a `brew doctor` command that might help you diagnose potential problems on your system. It’s a good place to start if it doesn’t work properly. `pip` doesn’t have that but it supports a `-v` option for more verbose output that can be used up to three times; e.g. `pip install -vvv ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Try brew install (your choice of package here). If that works, then that's good to go.

Try pip install (again your choice of package here). If that works, you're probably good to go.

If neither work, just try uninstalling brew and pip and then start again. If both work, you're probably good to go.

You can also get familiar with commands such as brew cleanup, brew upgrade, brew update, and brew doctor.

Hope that helps.